# Are Cookies Becoming Obsolete? Cookies vs. Browser Data Stores

Tags: javascript, html, cookies

I've been playing around with HTML5 and Javascript a lot lately and have been really impressed with the functionality of LocalStorage as well as SessionStorage. It got me to thinking - with the advent of these elements, is there really any discernible advantage to cookies anymore?

I am able to create both persistent as well as session dependent data (both lightweight as well as unhealthily robust objects) with these two data stores. What benefits, if any, do cookies provide over these? Is this the end of the road for our favorite web "treat"?

Comment: yes, overtime they will likely be unneeded with localStorage and other options that will come up.  Cookies were made ~1994, 20 years is a good run in technology

Answer (score 9):

> ...with the advent of these elements, is there really any discernible advantage to cookies anymore?

Yes: They get sent to the server with every request. That's what they were originally for, and that's their current purpose (well, and being a fallback for browsers that don't have web storage, but there are *very* few of those left). If you don't need the information sent to the server with every request (session identifiers, etc.), web storage or similar is your better choice.

Cookies were never a *good* choice for purely client-side data, because they add to the weight of requests and responses. They were just the *only* choice for a while. Now we have better client-side-only data storage choices, and we have cookies for the small set of use cases where you actually *want* information automatically sent to the server with every request.

Comment: Good point. A possible counter argument I could see, however, is also sending local storage objects to the server (asynchronously) using AJAX or other similar components. Though it may be more steps, would it not achieve the same thing? (Also just as interceptable/manipulable as cookies in transit, right?)

Comment: @mattkgross: Yes, but you'd have a lot more work to do. Consider a web site (not web app) with login. You'd have to rewrite all of your links either server-side when generating the page or client-side on page load in order to add the session identifier to them or to override them with ajax requests. For a certain class of use cases (that being the primary one), *small* cookies are the appropriate choice.